# Get Column Type of the columns in a database table

Tags: java, sql

I want to get the column name and column type of a table in java.As of now I am using the "DatabaseMetaData" class to get Columns and print the column name and column type as given below:

```
DatabaseMetaData Md=Conn.getMetaData();
        ResultSet rs=Md.getColumns(null, schema_name,table_name,null);
        while(rs.next()){
             columnName = rs.getString(4);
             columnType = rs.getString("TYPE_NAME");
             Columns.put(columnName, columnType);
        }
```

But in the db i have column as type "`VARCHAR2(300)`". I am getting only "`VARCHAR2`" as column type here.How would I get the exact type?

Comment: The size/length of the data type is returned in `COLUMN_SIZE`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-